# Changing Color of a Textview Over Time

Tags: java, android

I want to change color of a textview in android by passing time. For example I want to change a textview color one by one from 0, 0, 200 (RGB) to 100, 100, 200 (RGB)(all the colors included) with the delay of 100ms please help me what should I do?

Comment: use `ValueAnimator` or `ObjectAnimator` with `ArgbEvaluator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
//Code to set color 1
Thread.sleep(100);
//Code to set color 2
Thread.sleep(100);
```